# JPA query optimization

Tags: java, jpa, jakarta-ee, eclipselink, jpql

We have a JavaEE Web Application which runs on GlassFish 4.1. It performed well with small amount of data, but now data becomes more and more. The result is that a simple request like loading of a document takes about 1 minute to load, because it loads unnecessarily almost the whole database.

These are the entities:

**Document Entity:**

```
@Entity
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=JSOGGenerator.class)
@NamedEntityGraph(
    name = "graph.Document.single",
    attributeNodes = {
        @NamedAttributeNode(value = "project", subgraph = "projectSubgraph")
    },
    subgraphs = {
        @NamedSubgraph(
            name = "projectSubgraph",
            attributeNodes = {
                @NamedAttributeNode("users")
            }
        )
    }
)
public class Document extends BaseEntity {

    @JsonView({ View.Documents.class, View.Projects.class })
    @Column(name = "Name")
    private String name;

    @JsonView({ })
    @JsonProperty(access = Access.WRITE_ONLY)
    @Column(name = "Text", columnDefinition = "TEXT")
    private String text;

    @JsonView({ View.Documents.class })
    @ManyToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE },
                optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "project_fk")
    private Project project;

    @JsonView({ View.Documents.class, View.Projects.class })
    @OneToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REMOVE },
                mappedBy = "document",
                fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<State> states = new HashSet<>();

    @JsonView({ })
    @OneToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REMOVE },
                fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(
        name="DOCUMENT_DEFAULTANNOTATIONS",
        joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="DOC_ID", referencedColumnName="id")},
        inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="DEFANNOTATION_ID", referencedColumnName="id")})
    private Set<Annotation> defaultAnnotations = new HashSet<>();

    ...
}
```

**Project Entity:**

```
@Entity
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=JSOGGenerator.class)
public class Project extends BaseEntity {

    @JsonView({ View.Projects.class })
    @Column(name = "Name", unique = true)
    private String name;

    @JsonView({ View.Projects.class })
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "project",
                cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REMOVE },
                fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Document> documents = new HashSet<>();

    @JsonView({ View.Projects.class })
    @ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE }, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(
        name="PROJECTS_MANAGER",
        joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="PROJECT_ID", referencedColumnName="id")},
        inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="MANAGER_ID", referencedColumnName="id")})
    private Set<Users> projectManager = new HashSet<>();

    @JsonView({ View.Projects.class })
    @ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE }, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(
        name="PROJECTS_WATCHINGUSERS",
        joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="PROJECT_ID", referencedColumnName="id")},
        inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="WATCHINGUSER_ID", referencedColumnName="id")})
    private Set<Users> watchingUsers = new HashSet<>();

    @JsonView({ View.Projects.class })
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "projects",
                cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE },
                fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Users> users = new HashSet<>();

    @JsonView({ View.Projects.class })
    @ManyToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE },
                fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="Scheme", nullable = false)
    private Scheme scheme;

    ...
}
```

The data model is pretty complex and has partially cyclic structures.

The corresponding **DocumentDAO**:

```
@Stateless
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.MANDATORY)
public class DocumentDAO extends BaseEntityDAO<Document> {

    public DocumentDAO() {
        super(Document.class);
    }

    public Document getDocumentById(Long docId) {

        EntityGraph graph = this.em.getEntityGraph("graph.Document.single");

        TypedQuery query = em.createQuery("SELECT d.id AS id, d.name AS name, d.project AS project " +
                                    "FROM Document d " +
                                    "JOIN FETCH d.project " +
                                    "WHERE d.id = :id ", Document.class);
        query.setParameter("id", docId);
        //query.setHint("javax.persistence.loadgraph", graph);
        //query.setHint("javax.persistence.fetchgraph", graph); //evokes an exception
        Object[] result  = (Object[]) query.getSingleResult();

        Document doc = new Document();
        doc.setId((Long) result[0]);
        doc.setName((String) result[1]);
        doc.setProject((Project) result[2]);

        return doc;
    }

}
```

Before a simple *em.find(Document.class, docId)* performed slow as well. So the next trial was to create a *NamedEntityGraph* to override the fetching strategy. Passing the graph as a hint (*em.find(Document.class, docId, hints)*) didn't change anything. The same behaviour with writing a JPQL query like in the DocumentDAO. Assigning the NamedEntityGraph as a hint only evoked *"org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException.fetchGroupNotSupportOnReportQuery: Fetch group cannot be set on report query"*. I enabled the EclipseLink logging and I can see that the request evokes tons of unnecessary SQL queries.

The aim is only to return a Document object containing the id, name and the corresponding project object. The project object should only contain the users. I am also wondering why the *NamedEntityGraph* didn't change anything or am I using it not properly?

We use EclipseLink 2.6.2 and PostgreSQL.

**Update:**

Snippets from the logging:

```
[2016-06-05T17:50:27.875+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [FINE] [] [org.eclipse.persistence.session./file:/Users/timtoheus/NetBeansProjects/discanno/target/discanno-1.0/WEB-INF/classes/_DiscAnnoPU.sql] [tid: _ThreadID=31 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(3)] [timeMillis: 1465141827875] [levelValue: 500] [[
  SELECT t1.ID, t1.EndS, t1.NotSure, t1.StartS, t1.Text, t1.document_fk, t1.targetType_fk, t1.user_fk FROM DOCUMENT_DEFAULTANNOTATIONS t0, ANNOTATION t1 WHERE ((t0.DOC_ID = ?) AND (t1.ID = t0.DEFANNOTATION_ID))
    bind => [38]]]

[2016-06-05T17:50:27.877+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [FINE] [] [org.eclipse.persistence.session./file:/Users/timtoheus/NetBeansProjects/discanno/target/discanno-1.0/WEB-INF/classes/_DiscAnnoPU.sql] [tid: _ThreadID=31 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(3)] [timeMillis: 1465141827877] [levelValue: 500] [[
  SELECT t1.ID, t1.EndS, t1.NotSure, t1.StartS, t1.Text, t1.document_fk, t1.targetType_fk, t1.user_fk FROM DOCUMENT_DEFAULTANNOTATIONS t0, ANNOTATION t1 WHERE ((t0.DOC_ID = ?) AND (t1.ID = t0.DEFANNOTATION_ID))
    bind => [39]]]

... 

[2016-06-05T17:50:27.771+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [FINE] [] [org.eclipse.persistence.session./file:/Users/timtoheus/NetBeansProjects/discanno/target/discanno-1.0/WEB-INF/classes/_DiscAnnoPU.sql] [tid: _ThreadID=31 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(3)] [timeMillis: 1465141827771] [levelValue: 500] [[
  SELECT t1.ID, t1.LABEL_LabelId FROM ANNOTATION_LABELMAP t0, LABELLABELSETMAP t1 WHERE ((t0.ANNOTATION_ID = ?) AND (t1.ID = t0.MAP_ID))
    bind => [53649]]]

[2016-06-05T17:50:27.773+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [FINE] [] [org.eclipse.persistence.session./file:/Users/timtoheus/NetBeansProjects/discanno/target/discanno-1.0/WEB-INF/classes/_DiscAnnoPU.sql] [tid: _ThreadID=31 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(3)] [timeMillis: 1465141827773] [levelValue: 500] [[
  SELECT t1.ID, t1.LABEL_LabelId FROM ANNOTATION_LABELMAP t0, LABELLABELSETMAP t1 WHERE ((t0.ANNOTATION_ID = ?) AND (t1.ID = t0.MAP_ID))
    bind => [53650]]]

...

[2016-06-05T17:56:50.881+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [FINE] [] [org.eclipse.persistence.session./file:/Users/timtoheus/NetBeansProjects/discanno/target/discanno-1.0/WEB-INF/classes/_DiscAnnoPU.sql] [tid: _ThreadID=30 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(2)] [timeMillis: 1465142210881] [levelValue: 500] [[
  SELECT t1.ID, t1.LABEL_LabelId FROM ANNOTATION_LABELMAP t0, LABELLABELSETMAP t1 WHERE ((t0.ANNOTATION_ID = ?) AND (t1.ID = t0.MAP_ID))
    bind => [44220]]]

[2016-06-05T17:56:50.886+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [FINE] [] [org.eclipse.persistence.session./file:/Users/timtoheus/NetBeansProjects/discanno/target/discanno-1.0/WEB-INF/classes/_DiscAnnoPU.sql] [tid: _ThreadID=30 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(2)] [timeMillis: 1465142210886] [levelValue: 500] [[
  SELECT t1.ID, t1.LABEL_LabelId FROM ANNOTATION_LABELMAP t0, LABELLABELSETMAP t1 WHERE ((t0.ANNOTATION_ID = ?) AND (t1.ID = t0.MAP_ID))
    bind => [44221]]]

...
```

The total amount of queries is about 100.000. The logging refers to some other Entities which are not needed for this request. The end result should be about 500kb and not 7.1mb.

Chrome console:
[image: Chrome_web_console]

Comment: where is your debugging of how long different things took and why ? SQL invoked? other log entries? which field(s) is it retrieving? Specifying a "fetchgraph" on any query is totally valid and is a bug (IMHO) in EclipseLink to throw an exception when it is included.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know about your data, but this is what I think is happening -

You have the following eager associations

```
document -> project  (manyToOne is eager by default)
document -> states
project -> documents
project -> users 
user -> ... (this is not shown in question, but there could be other eager associations)
```

After you load a document with it's corresponding project -

1. all the project documents are fetched
2. all project users are fetched
3. all document states are fetched
4. for each document in step 3, document states are fetched
5. for each user in step 2, all eager associations are loaded

You see where I'm going. I see this as a combination of (n+1) issue and excessive use of eager loading even when you don't need it.

I would say 'Eager' fetching strategy is not ideal for complex object graphs. I would make most of the associations as lazy and load object graphs using 'join fetch' statements in JPQL.

Comment: So I am forced to write for every specific request an optimized JPQL query?

Comment: I've seen similar issue in several projects. For an optimal solution, it's better to write JPQL because you have more control over what is loaded. You still have to get rid of 'eager' associations, because even after executing a JPQL statement, eager associations are fetched using separate database queries.

Comment: Do you know whether there is a possibility to only select the projects users attribute in the JOIN FETCH clause and not fetch all the other attributes of project?

Comment: Don't think it's possible with your setup. All other attributes 'watchingUsers', 'scheme', 'projectManager' and 'documents' are defined as EAGER. If a Project object is loaded, all these attributes are retrieved. Try changing them to 'Lazy' if possible.

Comment: One problem is that if I create for every request an optimized JPQL query and set almost all FetchTypes to LAZY I can only determine which data is loaded eagerly in the first entity because JPA/ JPQL does not allow nested JOIN FETCH's. So if I have an entity model: Project->Document->Users
I can only specify in the query to fetch Documents eagerly and have no influence on Users. Maybe I have various requests and want in one request users in the other not.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'JPA/JPQL does not allow nested JOIN FETCHs'. This can be done in JPQL - 'from Project pro join fetch pro.documents doc join fetch proj.users usr join fetch usr.somethingelse'